# pauseAllEffects() not pausing sounds

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, simpleaudioengine

I'm using some sound effects and background music in my cocos2d-x app. When I try to pause using

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->pauseAllEffects()
```

it don't pause sounds. StopSounds also not working

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->stopAllEffects()
```

Although pauseBackgroundMusic() is working fine.
I'm playing effects that way :

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playEffect(fileName)
```

I also try by getting effect id and pausing that effect but it too doesn't work.

Comment: Where you use this function to pause all effects? There might me chances that somewhere in you code the function `playEffect(fileName)` get executed meanwhile.

Comment: I guess that is true. Can we do something like that sound doesn't play even when playEffect is called.

Comment: Yes, you can take a global boolean variable and check the value before playing any effect. If the pause state is true then don't execute your play effect method.

Comment: Thank you.I'm going to try that.